# Yammer JS SDK: Log in with Yammer button opens the popup window but never closes it. Yammer JS SDK

Tags: javascript, sdk, yammer

this is happening to us from some days ago and the component was working properly before.
We have a JS component using the Yammer JS SDK that renders the log in with Yammer button.
[Yammer log in button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhdQP.png)

First time that I visit the page, the Log In button is being shown properly, and when clicking on it, the pop-up window with the yammer.com/session/new is presented.
[www.yammer.com/session/new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eujnn.png)

When filling the user address, the popup does usual the redirections, but stucks in this page
[popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX2JH.png)

And checking the console in the popup window, it shows some errors:

- "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of null at checkRegisteredDomains..."
  [console error in popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SL7KR.png)

Checking the page where the component is placed, also shows some errors:

- "Refused to display 'https://www.yammer.com/platform-embed/js_sdk_login_proxy?ts=......" in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'...
  [Error in page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDZ3g.png)

If we close the pop-up window manually and refresh the page, then the component works, it seems that the token is already present, but in any case, it's a bit frustrating to have to close manually that window.

Is there any change in the Yammer API?
Should we change the way we are logging?
Any advice?